# Add two macro and convert to string in pre-processing stage

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

I want to add two macro definition and want to convert result into string in pre-processing stage itself i tried it in following ways but it doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TO_STRING_IND(arg) #arg
#define TO_STRING(arg)  TO_STRING_IND(arg)

#define ABC 1
#define XYZ 2
#define TOTAL (ABC+XYZ) 
#define total_str TO_STRING(TOTAL)


int main()
{
        printf("total %d \n",TOTAL);
        printf("total_str %s \n",total_str);
        return 0;
}
```

output of this program is as follows,

```
total 3 
total_str (1+2)
```

I expect total_str to be 3 in string.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I accepted answer by Matthias because that is what matches with what i was intending to do. But in other cases BLUEPIXY's answer is perfectly correct as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place where the preprocessor does any calculation is in #if statements. Otherwise the preprocessor makes only textual replacements. Therefore it cannot be done in the preprocessor stage what you are trying to do.

Comment: It seems you are right because i tried couple of things and it didn't work too :(, i was trying to add address and size of chunk and convert it to string in u-boot code and it started to break one feature then i realized the problem. Let me see if someone has any other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can in addition preprocessor in the range of up to 256(BOOST_PP_LIMIT_MAG) if You can use the boost.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/add.hpp>

#define TO_STRING_IND(arg) #arg
#define TO_STRING(arg)  TO_STRING_IND(arg)

#define ABC 1
#define XYZ 2
#define TOTAL (ABC+XYZ) 
#define total_str TO_STRING(BOOST_PP_ADD(ABC, XYZ))


int main()
{
    printf("total %d \n",TOTAL);
    printf("total_str %s \n",total_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AnkurTank  Why can not you use?

Comment: because ultimately i intent to use this kind of strigification in u-boot , i don't think i can use boost in u-boot.

Comment: @AnkurTank I think that it can use maybe if you can use the preprocessor of C.

Comment: '@BLUEPIXY: I think i can't because it uses cross compiler and i haven't seen boost in u-boot. To my knowledge Boost is not meant to be used in bootloader atleast right ?

Comment: @AnkurTank you should be able to use if you can use the preprocessor because only due to the preprocessor, not the full functionality of boost. And for example, you'll be even be applied alone preprocessor of the GCC (cpp).

Comment: Well it might work but in my project's u-boot code, no one would allow me to use boost preprocessor only for one stringification. currently i have hard coded it, i will have to ask seniors if its okay to use boost preprocessor, Thank you.

Comment: Well, you will be able to rewrite at yourself like this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

(ABC+XYZ) this will be replaced by (1+2). Then the TOTAL in your Program will be replaced by (1+2).

so printf("total %d \n",(1+2)); this will add the number and gives the output as 3.

But total_str will be replaced by "(1+2)", where (1+2) is a string.

The reason is TO_STRING((1+2)) will be replaced by #(1+2). # is Stringizing operator. it will convert the argument to string.

printf("total_str %s \n","(1+2)"); it can't add (1+2) because it is a string.

so you will get the result as (1+2).

Comment: Thank you for explanation, me too understand the issue but solution is not known :)

Comment: Question is how to make pre-processor to add 1 & 2 before stringizing it?

Comment: Add a macro for ADD 2 number #define ADD(ABC,XYZ) ABC+XYZ. then pass the result to TO_STRING(...). but you cant directly do it.

Comment: I had already tried it, it doesn't work! :( I think Matthias is right, but if there is some pre-processor trick then only we can do it. Otherwise its not possible to achieve this.

Comment: If you pass any argument to Stringizing operator it will automatically convert it to string. If you pass any variable it will print only the variable not its value.